# How do I calculate actions done per minute with Java?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writting a own application to help RuneScape 3 streamers educate their viewers with a DPS Rotation showing, and i'm wanting to implement a feature A.K.A APM (Which means Actions per minute) which is in other words, number of Keys (hotkeys) pressed within a minute, what i'm doing atm is, having a `LocalTime` when the thread starts, and every 5 secs it should show APM, but I guess my formula isn't correct.

Current formula is:
`LocalTime apm = Main.keysPressed.size() / (LocalTime.now().minus(Main.apmLocalTime);`

Which is:
***counter / (current_time - start_time)***

Problem is, the *.minus()* asks for a ***TemporalUnit*** as parameter, and i'm quite lost.

Can someone plz help me getting the formula.

Comment: Please show your current formula. Anyway given the (scarce) info, the formula should be `actions / time`.

Comment: ```LocalTime apm = Main.keysPressed.size() / (LocalTime.now().minus(Main.apmLocalTime);```

Which is ```counter / (current_time - start_time)```

Comment: And in what way is that wrong? What is the input data, what is the expected output, what is the actual output?

Comment: It asks for a TemporalAmount instead a LocalTime to be used as parameter for the ``.minus()`` and I'm not finding how will i subtract time from another LocalTime

Comment: The `Main.keysPressed.size()` gives me pause. First, that indicates a use of static (i.e. global) state which should be avoided. Second, that also indicates that you're storing the key presses in some sort of `Collection` which, over time, can end up holding a lot of elements (and thus consume a decent amount of memory). Unless you actually need to know _which_ keys were pressed I suggest just keeping a count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
actionsCount / Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ).toMinutes()
```

## `java.time.Instant`

Use `Instant` to track a moment, not `LocalTime`.

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen in UTC. The class resolves to nanoseconds, but current conventional hardware clocks limit capturing the current moment to microseconds or milliseconds.

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents merely a time-of-day without the context of a date and time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this class cannot represent a moment.

Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class for ease, and to make your code more self-documenting.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ) ;
long minutesElapsed = elapsed.toMinutes() ;  // Get a count of whole minutes in total span of time. 
long actionsPerMinute = ( actionsCount / minutesElapsed ) ;
```

Tip: While generally in Java we want to use the more general interfaces and superclasses rather than the more specific concrete classes, in *java.time* the opposite is true. In *java.time* we want to use the specific concrete classes, because the framework programmers told us so in the documentation. So if your IDE or compiler suggests a `Temporal`, for example, follow the Javadoc to see the list of implementing classes, such as `Instant`.

Comment: This is good, thank you <3